# When changing Activity in Android, how can I show a Splashscreen until the rendering of the Activity is finished?

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

When changing Activity in Android, loading of the contentView of the new Activity is very slow. Can I somehow hide the new Activity in the background, and show a Splashscreen until the rendering of the Activity is finished?

Should I use PopupWindow as a splash screen? 
What are my choices?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is you can use a `ProgressBar` to the user that page is loading.

Unfortunately in `android` we don’t have any `inbuilt mechanism` to show splash screen compared to `iOS`.

To start a `SplashScreen`, you can refer @ http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility of using a async task. This will run another task (your splash screen) as the pages finishes loading once complete it will refer back to the first task. Have a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

That has some good information about async tasks.